# Decoding the contents of a table using python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9HXp.jpg)

Above image is my working environment (i.e. Pandas (python))

I have a csv file, I transferred the contents of csv file into python.

```
file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename()
csv_file=open(file_path,'r')
pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

Now after the set of codes, I can display it's contents in Python pandas as a Table. 
Now I want to decode the Data in one particular Column "Batch"

In the picture, you can see a Table and in that table the particular column "Batch" is very important which is to be decoded.
**Look into the data under the **column Batch**.

**First Character** : Year

**Second Character** : Alphabet. It is mapped to a month (A-jan, B-feb,C- Mar, D- April, E- May.......)

**Third & 4th character** ; Date

**Ex: The manufacturing date for 6B08MK1D11 is 08-02-2016.**

Now I want to decode the every individual data in a column to find it's date based on it's Batch number. After decoding , I want to create a new column in which I have the values of seperated dates put into a new column.

For Example 
after decoding this data "6B08MK1D11" I get the date as 08-02-2016. Now for all such individual batch number, I will get individual date and now the new date values should be placed by creating a new column inside the same table.

After creating a new column, the Date column should be sorted A-Z (ascending).

I tried to teach how to assign months to Python: like following,

```
for everycode[1] in Bat:
    if everycode[1]=='A':
       everycode[1] = 'Jan'
    if everycode[1]=='B':
       everycode[1] = 'Feb'
    if everycode[1]=='C':
       everycode[1] = 'Mar'
    if everycode[1]=='D':
       everycode[1]= 'Apr'
    if everycode[1]=='E':
       everycode[1]= 'May'
    if everycode[1]=='F':
       everycode[1]= 'Jun'
    if everycode[1] == 'G':
       everycode[1]= 'Jul'
    if everycode[1]=='H':
       everycode[1]= 'Aug'
    if everycode[1]=='I':
       everycode[1]= 'Sep'
    if everycode[1]=='J':
       everycode[1] = 'Oct'
    if everycode[1]=='K':
       everycode[1]= 'Nov'
    if everycode[1]=='L':
       everycode[1]= 'Dec'
```

But When I execute this, it returns an error like this:

"*TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df['Batch'] = df['Batch'].apply(interpret_date)

def interpret_date(code):
   _year = replace_year(code[0])
   _month = replace_month(code[1])
   _date = replace_date(code[2:4])
   return '-'.join([_date, _month, _year])
```

You will need to write the `replace_...()` functions to map each input to the right values.

Comment: In the case of replace_month, how shall I teach python to understand that if it is A-January, B-February, C-March like that ?

Comment: There are many ways to do so, one silly way could be `if code[1] == 'A': return 'Januray' ... etc`

Comment: I was not able to achieve. or get the output. I don't know how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df['Batch'] = df['Batch'].apply(interpret_date).

```
def interpret_date(code):
_year = replace_year(code[0]).
_month = replace_month(code[1]).
_date = replace_date(code[2:4]).
return replace.join([_date,          _month,_year])
```

i think it’s something like this… might have improper punctuation…